# Same posts from my homepage are on all of my different page

Tags: plugin-wp-pagenavi

I see that you solved the problem of a WordPress user memo-maritime two years ago "Same posts from my homepage is on all of my different pages".The same problem i have.What should I do?I installed Pagenavi but not working.Theme by default(default.php) is something like this:

```
<?php endwhile; ?>

<div class="fix" style="height:20px"></div>

<p class="ar hl3"><a href="<?php echo get_option('woo_archives'); ?>" class="more"><?php _e('SEE MORE ARTICLES IN THE ARCHIVE',woothemes); ?></a></p>

</div><!--/box-->
```

Now I installed pagenavi and I modified it in blog.php:

```
<?php endwhile; ?>  

<div class="fix"></div>

<?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>
```

and in default.php I left as I mentioned above, nothing happens anyway, I tried.Contrary send me the exactly same page that is repeated on all 3 pages.I tried to fixed many times, but nothing happens,the same..I do not know exactly where would be this issue, maybe it is not there.If I change the theme,works!So the problem is the current theme..this function is repeated somewhere

Many Thanks in advance

Comment: please post the name of your theme.

Comment: Premiumnews theme by woothemes.It's free theme

Answer (score 1):

try to do the following in /layouts/default.php (and /layouts/blog.php):

- change the query line (line 5) to:

  `wp_reset_query();
  $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : (get_query_var('page') ? get_query_var('page') : 1 );

  $the_query = new WP_Query('cat=-'. $GLOBALS[ex_feat] . ',-' . $GLOBALS[ex_vid] . '&showposts=' . get_option('woo_other_entries') . '&orderby=post_date&order=desc&paged=' . $paged);`
- also add `wp_reset_query();` before the line with `wp_pagenavi();`

make backup copies before editing.

Comment: Many thanks!! you are the man! one thing ,if you put the code wp_reset_query();before the line with wp_pagenavi(); is visible on the page, so I deleted it and works.!I tired three days,finally done it!with your help i fixed,thanks again